# Search for keyword in T-SQL stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, search, stored-procedures

Whenever I'm developing stored procedures, I often need to do a find/replace or simply just find a keyword (string literal) inside the code.  I do this by exporting all of the schema and then doing a find in a text editor, like TextPad.

Where are stored procedures actually stored in the database itself, when you click "Modify" on any stored procedure?  That way I can find them and find text in the source code using some keyword without doing an export each time.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another great tool that would accomplish this is [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/), by Red Gate.  It's free and easy to use, I use it all the time.  It works as an add-in for SSMS.

Comment: This tool was very helpful for what I needed to do.  +1